# Select by multiple tags (whitelist and blacklist)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE stories
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  dir TEXT,
  alias TEXT,
  title TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE tags
(
  story_id INTEGER,
  name TEXT
);
```

Now I want to select all stories that have (at least) given N tags, and do not have another N tags.

Example: All stories with "fantasy" and "nature", but without "dragons"

Here's a query I tried (for now just the "whitelist" part, but it's extremely slow - so I'm sure I'm doing it wrong.

```
SELECT s.*
FROM stories s
WHERE 
   (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM tags t
       WHERE 
           t.story_id = s.id
           AND t.name IN ('fantasy', 'nature')
   ) = 2
```

If I add "LIMIT 10" at the end, it works (but very slowly).

No idea how to include the blacklist criteria into the query, though.

Ideas?

I have about 20.000 stories and 75.000 tag entries.

Comment: Answer if you want the points, but I have solved it in another way using a LIKE query on a column with all the tags concatenated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done with subqueries:

```
SELECT ...
FROM stories
WHERE id     IN (SELECT story_id FROM tags WHERE name = 'fantasy')
  AND id     IN (SELECT story_id FROM tags WHERE name = 'nature' )
  AND id NOT IN (SELECT story_id FROM tags WHERE name = 'dragons');
```

Alternatively, use a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) to combine the tag filters:

```
SELECT ...
FROM stories
WHERE id IN (SELECT story_id FROM tags WHERE name = 'fantasy'
             INTERSECT
             SELECT story_id FROM tags WHERE name = 'nature'
             EXCEPT
             SELECT story_id FROM tags WHERE name = 'dragons');
```

Which one is faster depends on the number of tags you're checking, and on the selectivity of your filters; you'll have to try.

Both queries are efficient if there is an index on the `tags.name` column.